# Unable to do any updates

Tags: apt, package-management

This has probably been dealt with, but I cant find a thread for it.
getting a Red no entry sign and BrrockenCount>0 message.
Advises to run apt-get but without success. Message says run package manager with right click but I cant find it??
If I chose updates it gives
The package system is brocken
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

Comment: Please add the exact output of `apt-get install -f` to your question.

Comment: it asks me to install root and when I do it says I have unmet dependencies, and to run  apt-get install -f  when I doo it says I am not admin (although I am) and to run root???

Comment: Again, add the exact output of the command to your question. "It asks me to install root" is not something we can work with.